# Is the exception object returned by ExceptionOccurred() still valid after ExceptionClear()?

Tags: java, exception, java-native-interface

In my C++ code, I want to test for a Java exception, get information about it, and handle it locally:

```
jobject exc = env->ExceptionOccurred();
if (exc) {
    env->ExceptionClear();
    jclass javaLang = env->FindClass("java/lang/Object");
    jmethodID j_toString = env->GetMethodID(javaLang, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

    auto s = (jstring)(env->CallObjectMethod(exc, j_toString));
    ...
}
```

I call `ExceptionClear()` right near the top because the call to `FindClass()` will cause a "JNI FindClass called with pending exception" error if I don't. But if I do this, will the exception object still be valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExceptionOccurred` gives you a local reference to the exception object. So it's not going to be affected by `ExceptionClear` unless `ExceptionClear` also clears the local reference table, which would be weird (neither ART nor Dalvik does that FWIW).

I think you can safely assume that `exc` is still valid after `ExceptionClear`. And if it isn't, you'd notice it because you'd get some kind of JNI error for using a stale local reference.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense since so many things would break otherwise.